# Javascript - set element's style property

Tags: javascript

I want to change DOM element's `style` properties. This is the way it works:

```
var el = document.getElementById("kaka");
    el.style.top = "10px";
    el.style.left = "20px";
```

But, I have many attributes to set, and they are stored in `Object` like this:

```
var style_obj = {
    top: "10px",
    left: "20px",
    backgroundColor: "#009966"
}
```

so i want to assign the `style` like this:

```
el.style = style_obj;
```

but this way it is not working, and this way too:

```
el.currentStyle = style_obj;
```

and even this way it is not working:

```
var style_str = JSON.stringify( style_obj ).replace(/{/g,"").replace(/}/g,"");

el.style.cssText = style_str;
```

So , what's wrong with a `style` and `currentStyle` ? How can i do it , without `for each` looping through the styles object??

Comment: just a suggestion. if you have too many attributes then make use of css class

Comment: Have you tried a loop through the object properties?

Comment: You won't be able to extend the object without a loop. Basically, you will have to reimplement [$.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) or similar.

Comment: I agree with Pankaj, you can do like this: `el.className += " newClassName";`

Comment: @PankajKathiriya in this object all that properties values are customized , no way to make class with them

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi what's wrong with a `style` and `currentStyle` properties , why can i assign it with a regular object?

Comment: @Cherniv, that's because both these properties are read-only. You can extend the object they refer to, but you cannot assign them another object reference.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi thank you , actually it is what i wanted to know

Comment: Why don't you wan't to use a for loop?

Comment: @Connor i just wanted to know what's wrong with a `style` and `currentStyle` , FrédéricHamidi explained that they are "read-only"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append a `<style>` element to the `<head>` section of your document containing the `style_str` variable...

but make sure you follow the syntax: `".class{"+style_str+"}"`

Or again, the simplest option is to **loop:**

```
for( prop in style_obj ) {
   el.style[prop] = style_obj[prop];
}
```

Comment: ok , i've tried that , can you tell me what's wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/U8aSh/1/

Comment: @Cherniv JSON.stringify adds quotes around everything, so you can't use that because it produdes this `#something{ "background": "blue"; }` that won't work

Comment: change the 16th line from `style_node.innerHTML = "#kaka"+style_str;` to `style_node.innerHTML = "#kaka{"+style_str+";}";`

Comment: So your solution is not relevant because it based on my `style_str` that you saying is not correct ?

Comment: no, you just have to remove the quotes around the word preceding the `:` but coming after the previous `;` with a regex

Comment: @Cherniv it's simple you can't do it without a for loop, and creating a style element adding adding content is going to so slow compared to style and would be hard to modify it.

Comment: @Cherniv you can still try my looping method.. i've tried my looping solution in your JSfiddle and it works..

Comment: @Cherniv do you want me to update your JSfiddle so that you can check it and use it?

Comment: it is ok , thank you , i know how to use it. i just wanted to know what's wrong with a `style` and `currentStyle` , FrédéricHamidi explained that they are "read-only". now i see that some smart j*rk down-voted this post , seems like i need to remove it now , or may be you want to up-vote it for save you 5 up-votes ? ;)

Comment: haha.. but it solves your problem right? anyways, i'll upvote you'r post okay?

Comment: there i upvoted your post which was down voted by someone else okay? by the way they *are* read-only... so accept my answer if it helped in doing what you wanted to do... :) @Cherniv

Comment: i've accepted your answer because i also was a newcomer on StackOverflow like you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign the style object like that. The style object is of type *CSSStyleDeclaration*. As assignment to it will fail silently. You can set and get its individual properties, as in `elt.style.color`. For more detailed information, such as the presence of an `!important` modifier, you can use its API, as in `elt.style.getPropertyPriority('color')`. However, to my knowledge there is no way to create a *CSSStyleDeclaration* object yourself.

You can of course also use the `_.extend` function from your favorite library, such as Underscore.js, as in `_.extend(el.style,style_obj)`, which is essentially identical to copying the properties over one by one.

You could also set the `.cssText` property on the element in question, if that floats your boat.

If by assigning the style object, you were trying at the same to remove all existing properties, then you'll have to do that separately; setting `cssText` to the null string should do the trick.

DON'T do this by appending a `style` element to the head, for heaven's sake.

Comment: Your favorite library can't be favorite for all. please mention the name of the library.

Comment: I have always known it to be `If it floats your boat`  you wouldn't want it to rock it.

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi, well, because there's no need to. It's an overly roundabout way to just set a CSS property on an element, which is all the OP was trying to do.